# How to change variable value using parent selector in LESS

Tags: css, less

So lets have following snippet:

```
.dashboard.tile {
    display: block;
    color:white;
    &-blue {
        @body-color:@light-blue;
        @footer-color:@dark-blue;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    @body-color:@greenBright;
    @footer-color:#000;
    div.tile-body {
        border-radius: @tile-border-radius @tile-border-radius 0 0;
        background-color: @body-color;
        font-size: @font-size-h2;
    }
    div.tile-footer {
        border-radius: 0 0 @tile-border-radius @tile-border-radius;
        background-color: @footer-color;
    }
}
```

My goal is to create additional classes like `tile-blue` `tile-red` etc that would only change color variable values.
Unformtunelty this does not work. `tile-blue` gets generated with `font-size:10` but variables are unaffected - more over, default color is not applied so I guess that i have messed something up with selector hierarchy etc.

Comment: In `&-blue` section you just override variables values but don't use them. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I bet you know what I want to achieve, and obviously I dont know how to do it. Do you?

Comment: In general the proper approach is exactly the opposite - you generate rulesets (classes + their styles) via variables/mixins, *not* like "you create a ruleset to set variables to create another ruleset". (I suppose you expect variables from `&-blue` and styles from `div.tile-body` to ombine into a *new* ruleset like `.dashboard.tile-blue div.tile-body` - but no it's not working like that (variables do not create any styles on their own).

Comment: In general it's a tricky to try to answer the Q since you're asking on the method *you think* would do the trick instead of *what* you're trying to achieve. (The idea itself is clear, but there're too many options and details to give aconstructive answer... Try to start with some "[less] theme/theming" query - there're tens of Qs like yours).

Comment: *My goal is to create additional classes like tile-blue tile-red etc that would only change color variable values.* - note that CSS preprocessors (like Less or Sass) are compiled into CSS w/o any variables (not counting custom properties that have quite different semantics), so when you define your goal keep in mind it should end in explicit classes+styles (i.e. in simple words the good starting point is "What CSS code I want to get in the end?").

Comment: Duplicate of [Less: Define color according to Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878988/less-define-color-according-to-class)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution that exactly suits my needs

```
.dashboard-tile{
    &-blue{
        .dashboard-tile(@light-blue,@dark-blue)
    }
    &-green{
        .dashboard-tile(@light-green,@dark-green)
    }
    &-red{
        .dashboard-tile(@light-red,@dark-red)
    }
    &-violet{
        .dashboard-tile(@light-violet,@dark-violet)
    }
}
.dashboard-tile(@body-color,@footer-color) {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    .tile-body {
        border-radius: @tile-border-radius @tile-border-radius 0 0;
        background-color: @body-color;
        font-size:@font-size-h2;
        #tilePadding;
    }
    .tile-footer {
        border-radius: 0 0 @tile-border-radius @tile-border-radius;
        background-color: @footer-color;
        #tilePadding;
    }
}
```